# Compositeness test for numbers of the form $E_n(b)=\frac{b^{2^n}+1}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the following claim?

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $E_n(b)= \frac{b^{2^n}+1}{2} $ where $b$ is an odd natural number greater than one and $n\ge2$ . Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{E_n(b)}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{a+2}{E_n(b)}\right)=-1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{b^2}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} E_n(b)$. Then if $E_n(b)$ is prime then $S_{2^n-2} \equiv a \pmod{E_n(b)}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjsEOgyAQRO9-hfVgoGAM9Ej36LG_YAKURlIFAqaNf981qUkPPc7bmZ0xcFFVAKmqAYgZ5RiYoD1KvR_ek58dOZFnjsHZp8tEd5IPFKATddvWP5wdnHLNGFVVgVu8E3lOcbaTM1uZ3Gtv4ILrXlJ0q8quGcRRg-IKOAAb_mcxWb5J9DIQ-ME_SAHQPGUfVtKkHI0281ajXlxDD27jkmLxKyL6AdBESEw=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

I have tested this claim for many random values of $b$ and $n$ and there were no counterexamples.